# Why Can't I See The Soft Keyboard When I Inflate A Layout With A WebView?

Tags: java, android

I have a donation option on my app in the menu. When the user taps on that an AlertDialog.Builder appears that will display a layout with a webviewer on it. The page loads just fine in the WebViewer in the AlertDialog. However, when the webpage loads and there is a editable text view on the webpage the keyboard will not popup to allow users to enter in their dollar amount. Here is what I tried...

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            adb.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_payment_32);
            adb.setTitle("Tip Developer");

            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tip_developer_layout, null);
            WebView wv = v.findViewById(R.id.tip_donation_webViewer);
            WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
            ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            wv.loadUrl("");

            wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

                }

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    wv.requestFocusFromTouch();
                    wv.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                }
            });

            wv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    switch (motionEvent.getAction())
                    {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            if (!v.hasFocus())
                            {
                                v.requestFocus();
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });


            adb.setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            });

            adb.setView(v);
            adb.create();
            adb.show();
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Wow, no answer yet. It's hard to believe that no one on here knows the answer, unless I'm not asking my question correctly? Do you folks not understand the question?

Comment: Does it not pop up when the user clicks on the field, or just not pop up when the webview is displayed?  Because I would expect them to have to click the field to get the keyboard, but I would expect it to appear then.

Answer (score -1):

Insert this code.

```
private void showSoftKeyBoard() {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
    }
```

Then, implement it in `OnCLick`.

```
wv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showSoftKeyBoard();
            }
        });
```

Add this line in your EditText.

```
android:inputType="number"
```

And insert this code.

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        wv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        wv.requestFocus();
    }
```

Comment: toggleSoftInput has actually been deprecated.  It was never a good thing to use for a couple of reasons.  First is that it isn't opening the keyboard to a specific view, so the input connection can be screwed up.  The second is that you don't know the initial state, so toggling it can close it.  Always use showSoftInput instead.

Comment: If this wasn't a webview the right thing to do would be to requestFocus on the view and everything would work.  But with a webview, that may or may not work.  Because focusing the webview is not the same as focusing the edit box within it, which would be needed to make everything work right.  Its one of those things that might work and is worth trying, but it may not on all versions of Android.